# Is it possible to see qsub job scripts and command line options etc. that will be issued by Snakemake in the dry run mode?

Tags: snakemake, qsub

I am new to Snakemake and planning to use Snakemake for qsub in my cluster environment. In order to avoid critical mistakes that may disturb the cluster, I would like to check qsub job scripts and a qsub command that will be generated by Snakemake before actually submitting the jobs to the que.

Is it possible to see qsub job script files etc. in the dry run mode or in some other ways? I searched for relevant questions but could not find the answer. Thank you for your kind help.

Best,

Schuma

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. If not, I think it would be really cool if `--dry-run --cluster "qsub ..."` showed what would be submitted to the cluster.

Comment: You can always check the snakemake source code and step through it with a debugger to see what's going on. Or maybe insert a custom `print()` in a good location so that it does what you want. Maybe there's a better way, but this is always possible and you learn about snakemake at the same time ;) For example, if you used slurm, you could modify this line to print what gets submitted: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/512e49b778261467dd8a31b5caa087a378ec32a3/snakemake/executors/slurm/slurm_submit.py#L209

Comment: You can find relevant source code here as well, just debug/print, snakemake is really easy to understand, source code is quite clear https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/512e49b778261467dd8a31b5caa087a378ec32a3/snakemake/executors/__init__.py#L636

Comment: Thank you Cornelius Roemer! It is absolutely true that we can see all the behavior of snakemake by looking at and analyzing the source code by using a debugger etc. I love snakemake so will try to understand it much more as you kindly suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `--printshellcmds` or short version `-p` with `--dry-run` will allow you to see the commands snakemake will feed to `qsub`, but you won't see `qsub` options.

I don't know any option showing which parameters are given to `qsub`, but `snakemake` follows a simple set of rules, which you can find detailed information [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cluster.html) and [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#snakefiles-resources). As you'll see, you can feed arguments to qsub in multiple ways.

- With default values `--default-resources resource_name1=<value1> resource_name2=<value2>`  when invoking snakemake.
- On a per-rule basis, using `resources` in rules (prioritized over default values).
- With explicitly set values, either for the whole pipeline using `--set-resources resource_name1=<value1>` or for a specific rule using `--set-resources rule_name:resource_name1=<value1>` (prioritized over default and per-rule values)

Suppose you have the following pipeline:

```
rule all:
    input:
        input.txt
    output:
        output.txt
    resources:
        mem_mb=2000
        runtime_min=240
    shell:
        """
        some_command {input} {output}
        """
```

If you call qsub using the `--cluster` directive, you can access all keywords of your rules. Your command could then look like this:

`snakemake all --cluster "qsub --runtime {resources.runtime} -l mem={resources.mem_mb}mb"`

This means `snakemake` will submit the following script to the cluster just as if you did directly in your command line:

`qsub --runtime 240 -l mem=2000mb some_command input.txt output.txt`

It is up to you to see which parameters you define where. You might want to check your cluster's documentation or with its administrator what parameters are required and what to avoid.

Also note that for cluster use, Snakemake documentation recommends setting up a [profile](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles) which you can then use with `snakemake --profile myprofile` instead of having to specify arguments and default values each time.

Such a profile can be written in a `~/.config/snakemake/profile_name/config.yaml` file. Here is an example of such a profile:

```
cluster: "qsub -l mem={resources.mem_mb}mb other_resource={resources.other_resource_name}"
jobs: 256
printshellcmds: true
rerun-incomplete: true
default-resources:
  - mem_mb=1000
  - other_resource_name="foo"
```

Invoking `snakemake all --profile profile_name` corresponds to invoking

```
snakemake all --cluster "qsub -l mem={resources.mem_mb}mb other_resource= resources.other_resource_name_in_snakefile}" --jobs 256 --printshellcmds --rerun-incomplete --default-resources mem_mb=1000 other_resource_name "foo"
```

You may also want to define test rules, like a minimal example of your pipeline for instance, and try these first to verify all goes well before running your full pipeline.

Comment: Thank you SJuhel! As you suggested, we can collect all the commands snakemake will generate by using --printshellcmds and --dry-run options before actually submitting the jobs. Together with the --profile option, especially by writing "cluster: "qsub -l mem={resources.mem_mb}mb other_resource={resources.other_resource_name}" etc., we can also explicitly define qsub options. Thanks again!